# java Calendar возвращает неправильный день недели

Tags: java, дата, calendar

При программировании на java столкнулся с проблемой, что календарь не всегда правильно возвращает день недели. Пробовал использовать как Calendar, так и GregorianCalendar, но результат одинаковый.

Для примера:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar(196, 0, 1);
System.out.println(calendar1.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Результатом в выводе будет 5, хотя по календарю: 01 января 196 - пятница, а значит мы должны были получить значение 6. Такая же проблема с годами:

- 1036 (1 января - воскресенье, а возвращает 5)
- 1316 (1 января - среда, а возвращает 5)
- 1456 (1 января - вторник, а возвращает 5)

и др.

Но иногда возвращает и правильные значения. Например:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(1600, 0, 1);
System.out.println(calendar2.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

вернет 7, и по календарю это суббота.

Comment: А с каким календарём вы сравнивали? Я накопал [первый попавшийся сайт](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weekday.html) - в нём "1 январь 0196 г. is a четверг".

Comment: @Regent Начинаю подозревать, что примерно до 1600 года все календари расходятся. На сайте, который вы дали, мои приведенные года отображаются в соответствии с java. Но вот например год 1583 расходится. В java 1 января 1583 года - суббота, а на сайте вторник.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу сам на собственный вопрос.

Такая неразбериха с календарями получилась из-за отличий Григорианского и Юлианского календарей. В Юлианском календаре високосный год наступает каждый год, который кратный 4, а в Григорианском - високосными считаются года, которые делятся на 4, но не кратные 100 (за исключением годов, которые делятся на 400). Это означает, что постепенно разница между этими календарями увеличивается на 3 дня каждые 400 лет.

Т.к. на Григорианский практически все страны перешли только с 1582 года, то до этого времени все ресурсы и языки программирования (помимо Java сравнивал еще с Python) по-своему высчитывают этот период.

Что касается Java, то, как я понял, до 1582 года включительно в языке используется Юлианский календарь, а с 1583 - Григорианский.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще один нюанс про который забывает ТС:

> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource data when a Calendar is constructed. They may also be specified explicitly through the methods for setting their values.

Грубо говоря номер дня недели зависит от выбранной локали. В русском календаре первый день недели - понедельник, в западной традиции первый день недели воскресенье.

Comment: Про этот нюанс я не забыл, т.к. в своем вопросе я привел примеры, где, например, для пятницы я ожидал увидеть 6, а получил значение 5. Я понимаю, что неделя начинается с воскресенья (значение 1), но к вопросу это не имеет отношения.